# Android:How To use Sub_menu category in menu options

Tags: android, menu, optionmenu

In My Activity i place a Option Menu like **Text Options** when the user click the text option an another option menu(Sub_menu) want to be load with text Colour and text size adjustment how can we do this in Android Plz help i am New To Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `menu_activity.xml` have all the `menu item` you want. If you don't want to show a `menu item` initially then set its visibility to false. `android:visible="false"`

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/text_options"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/text_options"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/text_color"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/text_color"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>       
<item
    android:id="@+id/text_size"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:title="@string/text_size"
    android:visible="false"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

In your `Activity` have the following methods:

```
private boolean isShown = true;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.findItem(R.id.text_options).setVisible(!isShown);
    menu.findItem(R.id.text_color).setVisible(isShown);
    menu.findItem(R.id.text_size).setVisible(isShown);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.text_options:
            hideMenu();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void hideMenu() {
    isShown = false;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

public void showMenu() {
    isShown = true;
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Once you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, the menu list will be recalculated, i.e, `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` will be called. Modify this a bit and you can achieve what you are looking for.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to add a sub_menu, then modify your `menu_activity.xml` to look like below:

> You can add a submenu to an item in any menu (except a submenu) by
>   adding a  element as the child of an . Submenus are useful
>   when your application has a lot of functions that can be organized
>   into topics, like items in a PC application's menu bar (File, Edit,
>   View, etc.). For example:
>
> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     <item android:id="@+id/file"
>           android:title="@string/file" >
>         <!-- "file" submenu -->
>         <menu>
>             <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
>                   android:title="@string/create_new" />
>             <item android:id="@+id/open"
>                   android:title="@string/open" />
>         </menu>
>     </item>
> </menu> To use the menu in your activity, you need to inflate the menu resource (convert the XML resource into a programmable object)
> ```
>
> using MenuInflater.inflate(). In the following sections, you'll see
>   how to inflate a menu for each menu type.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Thanks but When i Click Menu Options a new menu want to be display it contain text color and text size..TEXTOPTIONS->Click(New Option Menu)it contain TEXTSIZE AND TEXT COLOR @Henry

Comment: @vasanth Updated the answer. Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: Exactly But what abt in #MainActivity @Henry

Comment: You need not do anything there.. just inflate the layout in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`